# Is there a program that can select a set of 5 to 10 colors based on a few main colors?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design-patterns, color, design-theory

Say I want a color scheme to be 'vintage' and I know that, at least to me, that means a lighter sea green and a faded orange color.

I know the art students will understand color theory enough to do this from memory, but for the rest of us ...

how can I choose colors for a website that will look good together and not clash or annoy everyone. Is there a program or website that can do this quickly and easily?

Comment: You could try [Adobe Kuler](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/), i.e. set the harmony to triads and select a retro off-white as the main color.

Comment: Material Design has a great section on color and a tool that lets you see color combinations in a UI : [MD Color Tool](https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-Design with black and white first to get the contrast correct.

[image]

Technique used by concept artists and painters called "shading", they usually do in B&W so they can get the color correctly.

2-Go to Dribbble search by color or keyword, or get a scanned vintage poster and steal the colors from either one of those. Oil paintings can be also used in that sense. 
[image]My designer friend who worked in Branding always stole from Monet and Van Gogh.

3-Apply the colors to the website.
Trick: turn off colors from the OS so it's all grayscale.
Compare the original b&w wireframe with the version you applied color, you can overlap one with the other one using some squares. You can easily see the difference between the quantity of light on those , then using the HSL color scale change Saturation or Light to make them match , avoid hue because it is the actual color, and the less hues you have the better, unless you are doing illustration

Example:
[image]

with grayscale
[image]

When you say 10 colors it might be the wrong concept.
If I have #E9ECEF and #6C757D they are not two colors but one, because in HSL values the S and L are changing, it's like there are different light sources hitting the object and producing different variations. Try to use 1 primary color, a secondary color and accent. If you need contrast, then try to find a way to change them without changing HUE. It's not an exact science, also because colors change in proximity of other colors due on how the brain perceives it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gives me a great starting point to play with things. Most of the time when I post questions, 

I get feedback that I'm being too vague, but really the simple questions I can just look up online. It is the vague or opinionated questions that I need help with! 

Thanks for posting examples and a workflow that makes sense.

Comment: I get the same flames as you on topics I don't have much background. If you want to change the world, be the change you want to see.... I went through the same problem as you before, so I kind of know what you are trying to do ;)

Answer (score 3):

https://coolors.co/ allows you to randomly generate color schemes based on a fixed starting color.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [colormind.io](http://colormind.io/)
or [color.adobe.com](https://color.adobe.com/fr/create/color-wheel/) as mentioned in comments
to generate colors that look good together

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of the friendly responses. I don't always get good responses to my questions and I tend to get on people's nerves at times so I thank you for your patience.

I found this article by Micah Bowers, for those of us who are not trained artists, that I think will add value to the discussion: [Medium article](https://uxdesign.cc/color-theory-for-designers-a-crash-course-with-infographic-41d8b4c45619) It has great visuals and clear explanations.

I tend to be a rather vague person at times. If a question is simple, I usually don't discuss it. I look it up! I don't ask questions unless they are complicated and opinionated. This has led me to frustrating experiences on Stack xxx sites where opinion based questions are frowned upon.

I'm gradually learning how to just ask a simple question, even if I know the answer, and then expand on it after I get some interest. Eventually I'll get to the bits I don't know ...

Thanks,

Mike